# NumberFormatException & NullPointer Exception in Activiti Explorer

Tags: activiti, business-process-management, bpmn

Whenever I click on the Processes or Reports Tab in the Activity Explorer, It says "Internal Error, Please notify the administrator" and I get the following error in the console.

Tried searching for some similar errors in the activiti forum but there was no solution.

Can anyone help me with this?

```js
Jan 15, 2015 8: 09: 05 PM com.vaadin.Application terminalError
SEVERE: Terminal error:
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "23.15999984741211"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.MouseEventDetails.deSerialize(MouseEventDetails.java: 124)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java: 223)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java: 1460)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java: 1404)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java: 1329)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java: 761)

at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java: 325)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java: 501)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java: 727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java: 52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 208)
at org.activiti.explorer.filter.ExplorerFilter.doFilter(ExplorerFilter.java: 42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java: 220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java: 122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java: 503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java: 170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java: 103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java: 950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java: 116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java: 421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java: 1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java: 611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java: 2466)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java: 2455)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java: 61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jan 15, 2015 8: 09: 05 PM com.vaadin.Application terminalError
SEVERE: Terminal error:
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.activiti.explorer.ExplorerApp.terminalError(ExplorerApp.java: 246)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleChangeVariablesError(AbstractCommunicationManager.ja va: 1564)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java: 1425)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java: 1329)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java: 761)

at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java: 325)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java: 501)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java: 727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java: 52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 208)
at org.activiti.explorer.filter.ExplorerFilter.doFilter(ExplorerFilter.java: 42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java: 208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java: 220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java: 122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java: 503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java: 170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java: 103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java: 950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java: 116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java: 421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java: 1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java: 611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java: 2466)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java: 2455)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java: 61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is vaadin bug http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/9115,
try to update vaadin version.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone hit the problem again:
https://forums.activiti.org/content/activiti-explorer-runs-return-error#comment-35300

A possible solution is to set a servlet filter in the web.xml file to add a header X-UA-Compatible to the http response.
An alternative remedy would be to upgrage Vaadin to 6.8 version according to this post https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12635.